# MySQL sums from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple tables and I need to aggregate the data from all of them, but it seems that I always get the wrong results for the sums. **What am I doing wrong?**

```
customers
ID      Name   
1       c1
2       c2
3       c3

budget
ID      Cust_ID     Value
1       1           100
2       1           300
3       2           600
4       3           450

forecast
ID      Cust_ID     Value
1       1           200
2       1           500
3       2           100
4       2           700
5       3           550

orders
ID      Cust_ID     Net_Sales
1       1           100
2       1           200
3       1           300
4       2           400
5       3           500
```

Here is the expected result:

```
ID      Name        sum(budget.Value)       sum(forecast.Value)     sum(orders.Net_Sales)       count(orders.ID)
1       c1          400                     700                     600                         3
2       c2          600                     800                     400                         1
3       c3          450                     550                     500                         1
```

And here's what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT customers.ID, customers.Name, sum(budget.Value), sum(forecast.Value), sum(orders.Net_Sales), count(orders.ID)
FROM customers
INNER JOIN budget ON budget.Cust_ID = customers.ID
INNER JOIN forecast ON forecast.Cust_ID = customers.ID
INNER JOIN orders ON orders.Cust_ID = customers.ID
GROUP BY customers.ID
ORDER BY customers.ID ASC
```

Comment: You can add sample data in this http://sqlfiddle.com/ fiddle.

Comment: Unless your cardinality is 1:1 for each of the tables, your sums are going to be multiplied by the cardinality of the other records.  You either need to 1) Sum before you do the joins or 2) sum using an analytic.  There are other options but those 2 are the most common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are joining along multiple dimensions, which multiplies the results.

A simple solution is correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.Name, 
       (SELECT SUM(b.Value)
        FROM budget b
        WHERE b.Cust_ID = c.ID
       ) as budget,
       (SELECT SUM(f.Value)
        FROM forecast f
        WHERE f.Cust_ID = c.ID
       ) as forecast,
       (SELECT SUM(o.Net_Sales)
        FROM orders o
        WHERE o.Cust_ID = c.ID
       ) as net_sales
FROM customers c
ORDER BY c.ID ASC;
```

With the right indexes in the second tables (`budget(cust_id, value)`, and so on), this may actually be faster than a `JOIN` approach.